# How to make a horizontal scroll with dots using react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on one small part where I have to show some `divs` horizontally, so when it goes out of the space I am using css as `overflow-x:auto` so that it becomes scrollable.

**What I did**

```
<div className="App d-flex">
  {data.map((li) => {
    return (
      <div key={li.id} className="boxes">
        {li.name}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

My CSS below

```
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.boxes {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(196, 218, 243);
  min-width: 150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

**What I am trying to do**

- I want to put dots there so that when user clicks on dots it should scroll.
- the dots should trigger only when exceeded a number of items, means if there are less items which can be shown on one screen then no dots or else dots.
- Here I am not getting the idea how can I do this using react-hooks.

[Here is my Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-gwen-4dmivi?file=/src/App.js)

**Edit**
I am trying to get [image: This]

I want to show number of dots for each page , suppose on one page there are four divs so these can be shown in one page and no dots will be there, but when divs are 8 so it will come in two pages or three so 2-3 dots will come and when i click it should scroll to respective page as shown in picture.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you: https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs. There is a sample with cats.

Comment: @Azu I tied that but, is is showing on the basis of single divs I have multiples, can you help me with one working example as per my code sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need:

- An outer container to stay the width of the viewport and allow scrolling.
- An inner container to grow with the content and overflow the outer div.

CSS is as follows

```css
.outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Use the [Resive Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API) to listen for when either container gets resized. The outer container will be resized when the viewport size changes, while the inner container will be resized when the content changes.

Then just show the navigation menu if the inner container is larger than the outer container.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const outerContainer = outerContainerRef.current;
    const innerContainer = innerContainerRef.current;
    if (!outerContainer || !innerContainer) return;

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      setShowNavigation(innerContainer.clientWidth > outerContainer.clientWidth);
    });

    observer.observe(outerContainer);
    observer.observe(innerContainer);

    // Cleanup
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [outerContainerRef.current, innerContainerRef.current]);
```

In the example below, I use arrows and just scroll left and right to simplify. Making those dots is more complex since it involves calculating how many dots to show, and keeping track of their state. I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

---

**Snippet Example**

```js
let data = [
  {
    name: 'steve',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Matt',
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'michel',
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'Morgan',
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'joss',
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'stephen',
    id: 6,
  },
  {
    name: 'clark',
    id: 7,
  },
  {
    name: 'Simmons',
    id: 8,
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris',
    id: 9,
  },
  {
    name: 'Beven',
    id: 10,
  },
];

function App() {
  const outerContainerRef = React.createRef();
  const innerContainerRef = React.createRef();
  const [showNavigation, setShowNavigation] = React.useState(false);
  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(3);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const outerContainer = outerContainerRef.current;
    const innerContainer = innerContainerRef.current;
    if (!outerContainer || !innerContainer) return;

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      setShowNavigation(innerContainer.clientWidth > outerContainer.clientWidth);
    });

    observer.observe(outerContainer);
    observer.observe(innerContainer);

    // Cleanup
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [outerContainerRef.current, innerContainerRef.current]);

  function scrollRight() {
    outerContainerRef.current.scrollBy(outerContainerRef.current.clientWidth, 0);
  }

  function scrollLeft() {
    outerContainerRef.current.scrollBy(-outerContainerRef.current.clientWidth, 0);
  }

  function add() {
    setNum((num) => Math.min(num + 1, data.length));
  }

  function remove() {
    setNum((num) => Math.max(num - 1, 0));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="outer-container d-flex" ref={outerContainerRef}>
        <div className="inner-container d-flex" ref={innerContainerRef}>
        {data.slice(0, num).map((li) => {
          return (
            <div key={li.id} className="boxes">
              {li.name}
            </div>
          );
        })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="arrow-container">
        {showNavigation && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <button className="left-arrow" onClick={scrollLeft}>
              {'<'}
            </button>
            <button className="right-arrow" onClick={scrollRight}>
              {'>'}
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button>
      <br />
      <br/>
      <button onClick={remove}>REMOVE</button>
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.outer-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  width: max-content;
}

.boxes {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(196, 218, 243);
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.arrow-container {
  height: 2em;
}

.right-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**Stackblitz Typescript example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rq7fnm?file=App.tsx

Comment: I got your answer, but you have worked with one button only, I want to have one back button also so if I am on second page I can comeback to first page I mean there should be button to go back.

Comment: @manishthakur Sure, I added a button to scroll left too.

Comment: I found one small thing, why is whole screen is scrollable why not just the App container, I want only that to be scrollable, because below that I will have something else as well I don't want that to be scrollable, basically I just want that part to be scrollable.

Comment: @manishthakurmanish in that case you'll need two divs - one outer one to be scrollable and one inner one to be the flex box. The outer one should have width set to 100% and overflow-x set to auto. Then observe those two divs and compare their widths instead of the window / body. Call `scrollBy` on the outer div.

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check once.

Comment: @manishthakur I edited to just scroll the box container.

Comment: hi I got one thing, in same page if I want to have two section both will scroll independently, here I am facing issue please check this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z6m6te?file=App.tsx,index.html

it would be great if you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `react-magic-slider-dots` npm package and use your own CSS to match your design.
I have implemented this for your reference. Please have a look at the working [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slick-slider-4b6h3r) example.

Comment: Is there anything we can do without library

Comment: It is a very popular library and with this setup, you should now have a horizontal scroll with dots using react-slick. You can customize the settings of the Slider component to fit your specific needs. I would prefer to go with the library instead of writing so many custom codes.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem first. Code next.

### Solution

Observe the container div, the first box's div, and the last box's div and change the UI accordingly.

Keep booleans (simple variables are fine, state not needed) to check if the left button and right button are visible or not, by comparing against the container (if they are sticking or not).

### Code (idea)

Use `ref` to get the DOM nodes, (instead of `document.getElem...`, you know). Get their position and dimensions using `myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()`.

Pseudocode:

```
<div ref={containerRef}>
  {myArray.map((item, idx) => <div ref={idx === 0 firstBoxRef ? (idx === myArray.length - 1 ? lastBoxRef : null)}>...</div>}
</div>
```

You'll need to add the buttons, `overflow`, `max-width` properties and the [onClick scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), of course.

PS: One purpose of `ref` is to act as an alternative to `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/element), it covers this use case with its web components.

Here is the samples:

Using dots:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/uney2m?file=%2Findex.html

Using dynamic dots:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/49kqyp?file=%2Findex.html

Use the pagination clickable props to enable the functionality of moving to respective slide as shown in this example
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xp5tzz?file=%2Findex.html

Feel free to explore other types
https://swiperjs.com/demos